# Moving column to next line using Flex Box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three columns, ordering 1,2,3.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item first">1</div>
    <div class="item second">2</div>
    <div class="item third">3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background: orange;
    padding: 10px auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    flex-grow: 100;
    flex-shrink: 50;
    text-align: center;
}
.first {
    order: 1;
}
.second {
    order: 2;
}
.third {
    order: 3;
}
```

What I want when I switch to mobile screen columns should display like this;

```
1 3
2
```

**Media Query**

```
/* Too narrow to support three columns */
 @media all and (max-width: 640px) {
    .second {
        order: 3;
        /* And go to second line */
    }
    .third {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

Column two should move to next line.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/422j7/8/)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default the `flex-direction` is `row`, you should change it to `column` and use `flex-wrap:wrap` (we can write it shortly using `flex-flow:column wrap`). Note that to make the third column jump to the next column, the `.flex-container`'s height should be large enough to contain all the `.first` and `.second` **but** not enough to contain all 3 items.  With just that, you can recognize that the `.third` expand/strecth the whole space (on the second column). So you can try setting its `flex-grow:0` and use `flex-basis:50%`. Here is the code:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-flow:column wrap;  
    height:40px;   
  }    
  .third {
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-basis:50%;
  }
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/422j7/11/)

Here is another solution using ***column box*** layout instead of ***flex-box***, it works very well indeed.

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/422j7/12/)

Comment: doesn't work for me. Maybe some properties were changed

Comment: Nice 7 years later xD. But how can I do it, that all items after the 1 get down, and if it gets even smaller, all 3 are under eachother?